# Add Noise CIFilter

Tags: cocoa, core-image

Is there any CIFilters that have a similar effect to the Photoshop "add noise" filter?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [CIRandomGenerator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIRandomGenerator) in combination with some blend filter (addition, screen or whatever). Total effects chain should be:

- Generate noise map
- Blend it with the source
- Crop to original extent

Also, it could be useful to prepare own noise texture and write something like random generator using CIAffineTile filter with a transform that translates the image randomly.